# RecyclerView of heterogenous layouts is shuffling positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Well, I have a RecyclerView with two layout Types, it looks like the following:

```
public class SearchKeywordRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public static final int TYPE = 1, SERVICE = 2;
private ServicesViewHolder serviceViewHolder;
private ServiceTypeViewHolder serviceTypeViewHolder;
private Services services;
private Context context;
private OnSearchItemClickListener OnSearchItemClickListener;

public SearchKeywordRecycler(Services services, OnSearchItemClickListener OnSearchItemClickListener) {
    this.services = services;
    this.OnSearchItemClickListener = OnSearchItemClickListener;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (services.get(position).getSerficeType() == 1) {
        return TYPE;
    } else if (services.get(position).getSerficeType() == 0) {
        return SERVICE;
    }
    return position;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (viewType == TYPE) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_search_service_type, parent, false);
        serviceTypeViewHolder = new ServiceTypeViewHolder(v);
        return serviceTypeViewHolder;
    } else if ((viewType == SERVICE)) {
        View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_search_sevice, parent, false);
        serviceViewHolder = new ServicesViewHolder(v2);
        return serviceViewHolder;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return services.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Service service = services.get(position);

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case TYPE:
            serviceTypeViewHolder.setData(service);
            break;
        case SERVICE:
            serviceViewHolder.setData(service);
            break;
        default:
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return services.size();
}

public interface OnSearchItemClickListener {
    void onClickListener(int position);
}

class ServicesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txtViewService;

    public ServicesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtViewService = ButterKnife.findById(itemView, R.id.service_name);
    }

    public void setData(Service service) {
        txtViewService.setText(service.getService_name());
        if (service.getType_name() != null) {
            txtViewService.setText(service.getType_name());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        OnSearchItemClickListener.onClickListener(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


class ServiceTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewType;

    public ServiceTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtViewType = ButterKnife.findById(itemView, R.id.serviceType);
    }

    public void setData(Service service) {
        String name = service.getType_name();
        txtViewType.setText(service.getService_name());
    }
    }
}
```

The issue is items' positions keep shuffling while scrolling the recyclerView and I needs to keep its order fixed in the view.

As you can notice, I did used,
1- hasStableIds(true) function,
2- used getItemId() as suggested at most of Satck answers and posts.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that, I used a serviceViewHolder instance I created mannually to perform setData() function in OnMinderHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position);

After using the holder instance brought to me by the adapter itself, everything worked fine as it's synchronizing the holder instance matching the position used to retrieve the object from the data array.